# Byte[] Array to Int

Tags: objective-c, string, int, byte

I have a Byte with a length of 128. I want to be able to put these bytes into a single int (or string).

```
Byte *binaryKey = (Byte *)malloc(128);
// Adds 128 bytes to binaryKey
// eg. binaryKey = {202, 38, 255, 122, 65...}
```

I want to then be able to take `binaryKey` and put it into a single int (if not possible, even a string) like `2023825512265...`

Comment: Curious - why would you want a string of the bytes in decimal format with no way to tell where one byte ends and another one starts? The string `"2023825512265..."` could be parsed may different ways with no way to tell what it should be.

Comment: @rmaddy It's for quite a complex encryption method in which I'm converting from Java to Objective-C. (I didn't write the method, just re-writing for another platform). The bytes are apart of a key to use for encryption.

Comment: If you're porting it from another platform, what does that platform do? I cannot imagine that it is possibly employing latter approach (the concatenation the decimal string representations of the individual bytes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a string like this:

```
NSMutableString *keyString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
    [keyString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%hhu", binaryKey[i]]];
}
```

Comment: @Rob look at his example. This is exactly what he asked for. binaryKey = {202, 38, 255, 122, 65...} ---> "2023825512265..."

Comment: You're quite right. I read the question and, quite literally, I couldn't imagine that someone would write such a poor encryption algorithm. But re-reading it, this is what he asked for. Lol.

Comment: @Rob Blame Google.. http://codedigging.com/blog/2014-06-09-about-encryptedpasswd/

Comment: @Harry I'm not trying to blame anyone. But the code on that page does nothing remotely like what you've asked for here. That's a whole different kettle of fish.

Answer (score 0):

An integer has 2, 4 or 8 Bytes of size. 128 Bytes does not fit in it.

To create a string for it is quite simple:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:binaryKey length:128];
NSString *string = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
```

But why not using an instance of `NSData`?

Comment: Amin, I just tried this and it does not print the string in the correct format.

Comment: It's for quite a complex encryption method in which I'm converting from Java to Objective-C. The bytes are apart of a key to use for encryption.

Comment: I did not realize that you really want a hex format. To me it sounds like you would be satisfied with any string.